# Get maxmemory of redis azure cache from client

Tags: azure, redis, azure-caching, stackexchange.redis

We are using Azure Redis Cache and we need to monitor the state of it. One of thing we need is information about maximum memory. Currently, we enter the information manually, however we want to avoid it in future. Standard command used for this purpose `config get maxmemory` is disabled in Azure. For completeness, we are using StackExchange.Redis as a client.

Any idea, how to get the information? Also, why is the get version of command disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to get the maxmemory setting.  The "config" command is blocked for a few reasons.  One is that setting certain config settings could impact the stability of our service.  Another is that any changes to config would be lost if the server instance was restarted.  We are looking into ways to enable "config get" but keep "config set" blocked.

Here are the current values for maxmemory for each size cache offering:

```
Name      Size         maxmemory
C0      250 MB       285,000,000
C1      1   GB     1,100,000,000
C2      2.5 GB     2,600,000,000
C3      6   GB     6,100,000,000
C4      13  GB    13,100,000,000
C5      26  GB    26,200,000,000
C6      53  GB    53,300,000,000
```

Comment: I have asked Salvatore a few times for more granular permissions on commands; for example, `config get` would usually be fine, where-as  `config set` is clearly a bad idea for hosted scenarios; likewise `debug object` (fine) vs `debug segfault` (nooooo!); `client setname` (good) vs `client pause` (yeowch!); `cluster slots` vs `cluster addslots`... I will nudge them again!

Comment: With new update of Azure Redis Cache the INFO command start returning information about redis' maximum memory. It looks like Azure feature, so I think, it won't work it other hosted environments (not tested).